# How to get expire date in android flutter in-app-subscription

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-subscription

I reached the latest GooglePlayPurchaseDetails but cant find the expirey date/time of subscription. I only received the starting/purchase date of subscription. I have trial period so i cannot just add time in purchase date.